# How to display an RSS feed widget inside a page?

Tags: widgets, rss, embed

I have an RSS feed ([link](http://feeds.feedburner.com/RBloggers)) that I would like to display as a widget inside one of my posts.

The wordpress RSS widget already does that on the sidebar, is there some solution to have it in the post?

The best solution would latter let me do something like:

So I could embed this also on other sites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know php you could add it to a template using
wp function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget

or there is wp code to pull in a feed and list it
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

if you want a non coding solution, there are some plugins like:

http://webdesign.anmari.com/1649/shortcode-any-widget/

Comment: Interesting!  So if I want some URL which will have no theme around it, but only a simple page with a list of posts, what would you suggest?  Should I use a page with a custom template, and just use the WP code there?